# How WordPress sanitizes post content on save? Or it doesn't?

Tags: security, validation, sanitization

Does WordPress apply any kind of data sanitization for its post content when saving it from admin area? (like stripping `<script>` tags) Or all it does is checks for some user capability (like `current_user_can('edit_posts')`?

I'm asking, because I'm making widget plugin:

- It allows to add or edit HTML content which will be later shown of frontend .
- It can be edited by site administrator or editor.
- HTML content can have any structure, can contain script tags and can contain any attributes. So doing wp_kses isn't an option.

My question is, how safe is it do this without any kind of sanitization? (besides checking for current_user_can).

Comment: WordPress uses [`sanitize_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_post/) internally

Comment: There's a capability designed to allow users to add any HTML, including scripts. It's `unfiltered_html`. That would be the one to check when sanitizing.

Answer (score 1):

Safe against/for what? Is "a legitimate user can input any HTML" a safety issue?

If you might handle data from kind-of-but-not-really trusted users, how about giving admins the possibility to define which tags/attributes to strip out (optionally: per user group / role) and your plugin does the rest, or run the content through a filter where they can implement their own logic with `add_filter`?